# Jenkins+Groovy: Libraries

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Situation is simple - IN A GLOBAL LIBRARY (OUTSIDE THE SANDBOX):
in `src` - `a.b.c.Utils.groovy`
in `vars` - `Defaults.groovy`

How do I call `Defaults.groovy` from within `Utils.groovy`?

In `src`:

```
#!groovy
package a.b.c

public class Utils implements Serializable {
    def script
    public def run() {
         println(Defaults.text)
//groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Defaults for class: a.b.c.Utils
    }
}
```

in `vars`:
    #!groovy

```
public class Defaults {
    public static def text = "hello world"
}
```

in `Jenkinsfile`:

```
@Library("ItLoads")
utils = new a.b.c.Utils(script:this)
...
    utils.run()
```

so I tried to load the library explicitly

```
#!groovy
package a.b.c

public class Utils implements Serializable {
    def script
    public def run() {
         println(script.library("ItLoads").Defaults.text)
//Only using first definition of library ItLoads
//java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Defaults was defined in file:///apps/opt/.../vars/Ansible.groovy which was not inside file:///apps/opt/.../src/
    }
}
```

So, `Defaults` is defined somewhere, but I have no idea how to get to it...

If I try to use `Defaults` in the `Jenkinsfile`, it works.

HELP

Comment: Do you know the https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ documentation? To use steps you need to pass the this pointer to the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748932/how-to-access-pipeline-dsl-in-groovy-classesand-not-in-jenkinsfile/51752329#51752329

Comment: Reading both suggests that it is not, why would you think it is? Your reference explains how to call a library. What, in my question, suggests that it is unclear how to call a library? My question is how to get a value from the VARS directory so it is used by a SRC directory. smh.

Comment: Just looking at your example again I can now see that you indeed did pass the this pointer to the utils class. However you're actuallly are not using it in `Utils.run()`. Instead of `Defaults.text` I'd expect you use something like `script.Defaults.text`. Assuming that `script`acutally holds a copy of the script which I unfortunately cannot tell as the constructor is not visible in your example. Anyway I did not yet try to define static variables in `vars`. Therefore I cannot tell whether it'll work. The only thing I can tell is that it for sure won't without using the script object.

Comment: Adding the `script` did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, @JoergS, did you ever get this to work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744324/currying-groovy-cps-closure-for-parallel-execution. I am running into exactly the same problem, but found none of the references useful, as they did not explain how to deal with parallelism...

Comment: @JoergS, never mind about second question - figured it out. The thing that you want to vary inside your parallel closures has to be scoped to the loop, not outside the loop - this way you get a fresh variable with the right value every time...

Comment: @JoergS, can you answer the question as an answer, not a comment, so I can upvote it? By the way, you can see that I pass the script as a parameter in: `@Library("ItLoads")
utils = new a.b.c.Utils(this)
...
    utils.run()` But I should have used the map notation... I will fix my code sample. Thanks again!

Comment: Added an answer as proposed. Btw.: Yes, the curring is working for me. Unfortunately in that question you referenced you need to scroll down to the very last answer. Using Pipeline: Groovy Plugin version 2.40 did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I can see that you're not using the `script` object to access `Defaults`:
Instead of `Defaults.text` you should use something like `script.Defaults.text`.

Adding some links as a reference for future readers:

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/
- [How to access pipeline DSL in groovy classes(and not in Jenkinsfile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748932/how-to-access-pipeline-dsl-in-groovy-classesand-not-in-jenkinsfile/51752329#51752329)